# Mostrar botones dependiendo de cantidad de equipos e informacion de XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Esta vez mi duda si es algo compleja o al menos para mí ya que estoy empezando con funciones diferentes en `Asp.Net`.

Para intentar ser muy bien explicito, al iniciar mi aplicación, genero varios archivos XML en donde por ejemplo, uno se llama MyListOfMCH y contiene los siguientes valores:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<ArrayOfArea xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


-<Area>

<TOOL>MAK-1234</TOOL>

<AREA>FCH</AREA>

<POOL>Pool 30</POOL>

<TEAM>514</TEAM>

<STATION>1020</STATION>

<OPERATION>Apriete pedal del clutch</OPERATION>

<TORQUE>30</TORQUE>

<TL_NAME>cesar</TL_NAME>

<STATUS>Ok</STATUS>

<STANDBY>0</STANDBY>

<REG_DATE>Monday, June 19, 2017</REG_DATE>

</Area>


-<Area>

<TOOL>SAM-15946</TOOL>

<AREA>FCH</AREA>

<POOL>Pool 30</POOL>

<TEAM>513</TEAM>

<STATION>1020</STATION>

<OPERATION>Apriete pedal del clutch</OPERATION>

<TORQUE>30</TORQUE>

<TL_NAME>Carlos</TL_NAME>

<STATUS>Ok</STATUS>

<STANDBY>1</STANDBY>

<REG_DATE>Monday, June 19, 2017</REG_DATE>

</Area>


-<Area>

<TOOL>NAÑM-46</TOOL>

<AREA>FCH</AREA>

<POOL>Pool 30</POOL>

<TEAM>516</TEAM>

<STATION>1020</STATION>

<OPERATION>Apriete de pedal</OPERATION>

<TORQUE>30</TORQUE>

<TL_NAME>Carmelo</TL_NAME>

<STATUS>OK</STATUS>

<STANDBY>0</STANDBY>

<REG_DATE>Monday, June 19, 2017</REG_DATE>

</Area>

</ArrayOfArea>
```

Como pueden ver tengo 3 equipos, 513, 514 y 516. En otros archivos XML tengo información similar pero con Team's diferentes.

Tengo tres botones con sus archivos XML respectivos, dichos botones activan un modal

Estos son los botones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En dicho modal tengo varios botones con la propiedad de estilo `display:none`

Algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi intención es que dependiendo de la cantidad de equipos (ya previamente definidos) se muestre cierta cantidad de botones (quiero usar los mismos botones para todos) y que los nombres de los Team's cambien en cada botón dependiendo del archivo XML que se mande a llamar...

Es decir como se muestra en la imagen anterior.
 Espero haber sido explícito y me puedan ayudar a resolver mi duda. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

en el controlador envía la Lista de equipos

en la vita tienes que decir que va a recibir un modelo tipo equipos
@model IEnumerable

utiliza un

@foreach (var equipo in equipos) 
{
  mi codigo para dibujar el boton 
}

Comment: me podrias ayudar con el codigo para dibujar el boton? he creadio una lista de botones `List<Button> ListaBotones = new List<Button>();`